# without page refresh dropdown selected value to get data form api vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

topbar.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount ,reactive} from 'vue';
import { useLayout } from '@/layout/composables/layout';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import ApiService from '../services/api.service';

const { layoutConfig, onMenuToggle, contextPath } = useLayout();
//const state = ref(null);
const outsideClickListener = ref(null);
const topbarMenuActive = ref(false);
const router = useRouter();
const items =[];

const dropdownItems = ref(items);
const dropdownItem = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
    
  ApiService.getStores().then((data) => {
    data.forEach((value) => {
      items.push({ name: value.shop,value:value.id });
    });
  });
});


const onSelectChange  = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('shop-id',dropdownItem.value);
  //console.log(dropdownItem.value);
}
</script>

<Dropdown id="state" v-model="dropdownItem" :options="dropdownItems" :filter="true" 
            optionLabel="name" optionValue="value" @change="onSelectChange()"></Dropdown>
```

api.service

```
async getProduct() {
    if(!shop)
    {
      return axios.get(API_URL+'/product/all?id=1', { headers: authHeader() })
      .then((res) => res.data);
    }
    else{
      return axios.get(API_URL+'/product/all?id='+shop, { headers: authHeader() })
      .then((res) => res.data);
    }
   
  }
```

here dropdown selcted value to id set localstorage after pass axios services api its working fine only
when i page refresh.
but i want to without page refresh dropdown selected value to get data form api.
how to solve this?

Comment: Just call `apiService` from `onSelectChange`, using the dropdown value as the api parametter?

Comment: there is lot of services example(getProduct,getshop...)

Comment: `@change` is an attribute that can trigger function on select/dropdown change so use it!